# Is my encryption safe?

Tags: java, encryption

I made a own encryption and I would like to know wether it is safe or not.

First of all, its written in Java.

I started with this String:

> "Never gonna give you up, never gonna let you down"

it ends as a byte array when encrypted, but for visualizing, I changed it to hexadecimal.

> "6b4053405705424a4b4b4405424c5340055c4a5005505509054b4053405705424a4b4b4405494051055c4a5005414a524b"

now is it safe or should i rethink?

Comment: So you came up with a new encryption algorithm. How would you want us to give feedback if we don't know how it works? Or is the algorithm used itself the secret? If so, history turned out that this is **absolutely not** safe for passed/future encryptions.

Comment: It is unsafe.  I refer often to Bruce Schneier and will again here.  Paraphrasing, anyone can make a cipher that he cannot break.  Making a cipher nobody else can break is very hard.  A bit more harshly, before you tell us you could not break this, tell us how you broke RC4.  And if you have not broken RC4 and cannot break it, your claims to be unable to break your own homemade cipher are meaningless.

Comment: I would like to add that the encryption uses a key (like the majority of ciphers does) and uses it once in "text" form and as a hash in XOR to each individual byte of the array to encrypt

Comment: And by the way the result is in hex

Answer (score 4):

Converting each pair of characters as a byte value to ascii gives

`k@S@W BJKKD BLS@ \JP PU K@S@W BJKKD I@Q \JP AJRK`

which is just a simple substitution cipher.

They have these in the newspaper, and people solve them with a pen and paper.

Comment: It is totally unsafe, Rasmus.  Strong ciphers apply the key, XOR, bit rotate, add, S-Box (or some combo) in such a way as to produce the avalanche effect.  Not one bit of the original is safe from being flipped.  The output should look random.  Your output is definitely not random and probably has some patterns that repeat with a period corresponding to the length of your key.  Unless you are just hiding trivial secrets from a child, please do not use this algorithm.  It is not secure.

Comment: But let me set generalities aside for a moment.  As airza said, it is a simple substitution cipher.  K in cipher text equals N in plain text.  @ in cipher text equals E in plain text.  And so on.  You gave us this, but by frequency analysis it could be learned anyway.  And once enough plain text is learned, and how it corresponds to the cipher text, your key is revealed.  A good cryptanalyst would read your plaintext faster than I typed this comment.